# Angular 4 'ng build' error resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular, angular-cli, semantic-ui

I recently updated all my packages in my package.json file as below. But now on during 'ng build' i'm getting this error which i have no idea how to resolve, does anyone have any ideas on how i would resolve this? I'm using components from a package online which can be found here https://github.com/lon-yang/angular2-semantic-ui

```
      Package.json:

      {
        "name": "moto-duel",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "license": "MIT",
        "angular-cli": {},
        "scripts": {
          "start": "ng serve",
          "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
          "test": "ng test",
          "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
          "e2e": "protractor"
        },
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
          "@angular/animations": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/common": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/core": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/forms": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/http": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.2",
          "@angular/router": "^4.1.2",
          "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
          "angular2-semantic-ui": "^2.0.2",
          "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
          "codelyzer": "^3.0.1",
          "core-js": "^2.4.1",
          "firebase": "^3.9.0",
          "jasmine-core": "^2.6.1",
          "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
          "karma": "^1.7.0",
          "moment": "^2.18.1",
          "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
          "protractor": "^5.1.1",
          "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
          "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
          "ts-node": "^3.0.4",
          "typescript": "^2.3.2",
          "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.6",
          "zone.js": "^0.8.10"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "@angular/cli": "^1.0.3",
          "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.2",
          "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
          "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
          "@types/node": "^7.0.18",
          "codelyzer": "^3.0.1",
          "jasmine-core": "^2.6.1",
          "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
          "karma": "^1.7.0",
          "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
          "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
          "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
          "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
          "protractor": "^5.1.1",
          "ts-node": "^3.0.4",
          "tslint": "^5.0.0",
          "typescript": "^2.3.2",
          "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.6"
        }
      }
```

.

```
 Module:
      import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
      import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

      import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';
      import { AdminRoutingModule, routedComponents } from './admin-routing.module';
      import { CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-semantic-ui';
      import { DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-semantic-ui';

      @NgModule({ 
        imports: [
          AdminRoutingModule,
          FormsModule,
          CoreModule
        ],
        exports:[
          CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES,
          DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES
        ],
        declarations: [
          routedComponents,
          CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES,
          DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES
        ]
      })
      export class AdminModule { }
```

.

```
 ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only
  initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value 
 of this variable is needed by the template compiler (position 2:22 in the
  original .ts file), resolving symbol CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES in 
 C:/MotoDuel/node_modules/angular2-semantic-ui/components/checkbox/index.d.ts, 
 resolving symbol CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES in C:/MotoDuel/node_modules/angular2-
 semantic-ui/index.d.ts, resolving 
 symbol AdminModule in C:/MotoDuel/src/app/admin/admin.module.ts, 
 resolving symbol AdminModule in C:/MotoDuel/src/app/admin/admin.module.ts
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: can you point out this file (position 2:22 in the
  original .ts file)

Comment: I changed the export in the node_modules/angular2-semantic-ui/components/checkbox/index.d.ts file from:
     export declare const CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES: Array<any>;
to
     export class CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES{}

And it fixed all my issues, i did this for each component i am currently using in the project which is only the checkboxes and the dropdowns.

Comment: Please update it in the question

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for a temp. fix it seems by changing the export in the

```
 node_modules/angular2-semantic-ui/components/checkbox/index.‌​d.ts
```

from:

```
 export declare const CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES: Array<any>;
```

to

```
 export class CHECKBOX_DIRECTIVES{}
```

And it fixed all my issues... i did this for each component i am currently using in the project which is only the checkboxes and the dropdowns. Perhaps this can be changed on the primary repo.

Thanks for checking it out.